# Dll load failed, in python 2.7 running on windows 8.1

Tags: python-2.7

I'am using Boneh-Lynn-Shacham Identity Based Signature scheme for my final year project for getting encryption keys

```
from charm.toolbox.pairinggroup import *
from charm.engine.util import *
debug = False
class IBSig():
    def __init__(self, groupObj):
        global group
        group = groupObj

    def dump(self, obj):
        ser_a = serializeDict(obj, group)
        return str(pickleObject(ser_a))

    def keygen(self, secparam=None):
        g, x = group.random(G2), group.random()
        g_x = g ** x
        pk = { 'g^x':g_x, 'g':g, 'identity':str(g_x), 'secparam':secparam }
        sk = { 'x':x }
        return (pk, sk)

    def sign(self, x, message):
        M = self.dump(message)
        if debug: print("Message => '%s'" % M)
        return group.hash(M, G1) ** x

    def verify(self, pk, sig, message):
        M = self.dump(message)
        h = group.hash(M, G1)
        if pair(sig, pk['g']) == pair(h, pk['g^x']):
            return True  
        return False 

def main():
    groupObj = PairingGroup('../param/d224.param')

    m = { 'a':"hello world!!!" , 'b':"test message" }
    bls = IBSig(groupObj)

    (pk, sk) = bls.keygen(0)

    sig = bls.sign(sk['x'], m)

    if debug: print("Message: '%s'" % m)
    if debug: print("Signature: '%s'" % sig)     
    assert bls.verify(pk, sig, m)
    if debug: print('SUCCESS!!!')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    debug = True
    main()
```

when I am implementing it in python the code was not able to find the module named pairing though I have added Charm module to my library.Getting error like

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\Sailesh\Desktop\bls.py", line 1, in <module>
   from charm.toolbox.pairinggroup import *
 File "C:\Python27\lib\charm\toolbox\pairinggroup.py", line 2, in <module>
   from charm.core.math.pairing import serialize 
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I have taken the code from
[Boneh-Lynn-Shacham Identity Based Signature code](https://code.google.com/p/charm-crypto/source/browse/trunk/schemes/sig_short_bls04.py?r=120) and downloaded the module charm from [charm module link](https://github.com/JHUISI/charm/downloads). Let me know where is the error or whether the
problem is with the module. I cant figure out what is the problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you use the .exe installer? or the zip package?

Answer (score 0):

Try the 0.43 version directly fron github:

https://github.com/JHUISI/charm/releases